# Haskell - How to print some value in a function for debugging purpose?

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell newbie and I want to do something which has a side effect like this:

```
i = 3.0

main :: IO ()
main = let m = print i in putStrLn "Hello world"
```

Then I can know the value of `i` when `main` runs, but the `I` didn't print. I add `!` before `m` but it also doesn't work. I would like to know how to hack this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an `IO` action, you can just use `putStrLn` or `print` as usual, like

```
do
  print i
  putStrLn "Hello world"
```

Which desugars to `print i >> putStrLn "…"`. This is equivalent, but not really any better because the action `m` doesn’t really need to be named:

```
let m = print i  -- define an action
in do
  m  -- ensure the action is actually executed
  putStrLn "Hello world"
```

In a pure function, you can use `trace` or `traceShow` from `Debug.Trace`:

```
traceShow i (putStrLn "Hello world")
```

But be aware that these print when the expression is *forced*, which may be in a different order than you may expect due to lazy evaluation, or not at all if a value is never used. You can add strictness annotations with `seq` or `BangPatterns` as you tried for the monadic code to assist with making sure that things are forced when you expect—the reason `!m = …` didn’t work for your `IO` action is that the strictness annotation only makes the expression *evaluated*, producing an `IO` action but not *executing* it because it’s not sequenced with another action as part of `main`. Remember: you can only (purely) *construct* `IO` actions and bind them together; the runtime is what actually executes them.

Finally, in a “pure” monad where you don’t have `IO` available, you can still use `trace` &c., for example in the list monad:

```
numbers :: [Int]
numbers = do
  x <- [1, 2, 3]
  traceShow x (pure ())
  y <- [4, 5, 6]
  traceShow y (pure ())
  pure (x * y)
```

Answer (score 5):

For debugging, use `trace`  and friends.

```
import Debug.Trace
i = 3.0

main :: IO ()
main = traceShow i $ putStrLn "Hello world"
```

[See it live](https://ideone.com/4RWp2P)

Note the trace appears on the standard *error* stream, as debugging output should.

The function you use `trace` in doesn't have to be IO-typed. This for example will also work:

```
add a b = a + traceShow i b
```

Trace functions are a bit foreign to Haskell because they are technically impure. However the side effects are limited in scope and not observable by the program itself, so it's kinda OK.

[More info](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.12.0.0/Debug-Trace.html)

Answer (score 3):

You created `m` but never used it. To fix that you can try:

```
i = 3.0

main :: IO ()
main = let m = print i in m >> putStrLn "Hello world"
```

Comment: Is there a way to execute the side effect without using it? If the type in the left side of `>>` different from the right one, it will not work.

Comment: For the first question answer is "no". For the second: It should have type `IO a` with any `a` because `>>` ignores result of left argument.